# Symfony acl and role hierarchy in dashboard

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am pretty new to symfony and try to handle that framework.
Use symfony 2.8 with sonata admin 2.3 and user bundle 2.2.5
Got some interesting situation with ACL roles adding.
I have 2 roles in my project(user and admin) and needed to add one more(manager), but got stuck on situation with total ignore of any of that new role.
I am allowed to log in with the no problems but no dashboard is loaded to the admin_pool.

It's a part of my security.yml with allowed roles.

```
acl:
   connection: default

providers:
   fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER: [VIEW, LIST]
        ROLE_ADMIN:  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_DIVISION_MANAGER: [OPERATOR, EXPORT, MASTER, OWNER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

and a part of my config.yml
where roles should be influence dashboard view.

```
dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                position: left
                type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
                settings:
                    groups: [sonata_divison]

        groups:
            grower.management:
                label: "Grower Management"
                roles: [ADMIN]

            sonata_user:
                label: "Users"
                roles: [ADMIN]

            sonata_divison:
                label: "Division Management"
                roles: [ROLE_DIVISION_MANAGER, DIVISION_MANAGER]
                items:
                    - admin.grower
                    - sonata.user.admin.user

    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl

        # acl security information
        information:
            OPERATOR: OPERATOR
            EXPORT: EXPORT
            LIST: LIST
            VIEW: VIEW
            USER:     [VIEW, LIST]
            DIVISION_MANAGER:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER, OWNER]
```

Are there any thoughts why dashboard is blank for division manager?